No meta znode available Error When Connecting to HBase (Standalone)
I'm trying to connect to an HBase standalone instance using the Java API, but I’m encountering the following error:
21:58:06.527 [ReadOnlyZKClient-192.168.142.129:2181@0x7bb58ca3-SendThread(192.168.142.129:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x192b47ed5110005 after 1ms
21:58:13.231 [ReadOnlyZKClient-192.168.142.129:2181@0x7bb58ca3-SendThread(192.168.142.129:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply sessionid:0x192b47ed5110005, packet:: clientPath:/hbase serverPath:/hbase finished:false header:: 47,8  replyHeader:: 47,105,0  request:: '/hbase,F  response:: v{'running,'rs,'splitWAL,'backup-masters,'flush-table-proc,'draining,'master-maintenance,'online-snapshot,'hbaseid,'table,'switch,'master}
21:58:13.232 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl - Call exception, tries=13, retries=16, started=88564 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=No meta znode available, details=row 'test_table' on table 'hbase:meta' at null, see https://s.apache.org/timeout, exception=java.io.IOException: No meta znode available
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZKConnectionRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZKConnectionRegistry.java:144)
    ...

When I run the Java API, the code successfully connects to HBase and creates the table test_table, but it throws the error No meta znode available.
Could someone help me figure out why this error occurs when the test_table is successfully created in HBase? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here's the Java code I’m using to connect:
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    config.set("hbase.defaults.for.version.skip", "true");

    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.142.129");
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
    config.set("hbase.master", "192.168.142.129:60010"); // HBase Master address

    try (Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
         Admin admin = connection.getAdmin()) {

        TableName tableName = TableName.valueOf("test_table");
        String columnFamily = "cf";

        if (!admin.tableExists(tableName)) {
            HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(tableName);
            tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(columnFamily));
            admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);
            System.out.println("Table created successfully.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Table already exists.");
        }


